# Prepend and close a post with Ajax (in WordPress)

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a menu on the left which shows a list of post titles:

```
<ul id="post-title-list">
    <li><a href="url" class="post-link">Post title 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="url" class="post-link">Post title 02</a></li>
    <li><a href="url" class="post-link">Post title 03</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

On the right I have an empty div for the content:

```
<div class="single-post-container"></div>
```

The content is loaded with Ajax:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
 $(".post-link").click(function(){
     var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
     $(".single-post-container").load(post_link);
 return false;
 });
```

This is working nice and smooth, but clicking on a link replace the previous content with the new one. Instead, I want to add this, above the content already there.

This should be the result:

```
<div class="single-post-container">Last clicked menu item</div>
...
<div class="single-post-container">Third clicked menu item</div>
<div class="single-post-container">Second clicked menu item</div>
<div class="single-post-container">First clicked menu item</div>
```

And, when clicked again in the menu, the content should disappear.

Where do I have to look to make this work? I already tried to get this result with Metafizzy Isotope, but that's the wrong approach I think. I guess I just need to prepare that div for the next click.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use JQuery's [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), instead of `load()`:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
 $(".post-link").click(function(){
     var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
     $(".wrapper").prepend(post_link);
     return false;
 });
```

Also, you should wrap your `single-post-container` on a div as in:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='single-post-container'></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: With your help I was able to figure out how to combine `prepend()` and `load()`. Otherwise only the url was loaded, and not the content: `$('<div>').prependTo('#main').load(post_link);`

Comment: Leaves open the question how to close that div from the menu. The loaded content has an ID, so it's easy to refer to. Or does JQuery also has a sort of toggle for this purpose?